# Julia sequence : $u_n$ is bounded if and only if $|u_k|\leq 2$ for all $k$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $u_0\in \mathbb{C}$ and $c \in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|c| \leq 2$  and $u_{n+1}=u_n^2+c$.
>
> Show that  $u_n$ is bounded if and only if $|u_k|\leq 2$ for all $k$.

The first implication is trivial.

Then, I have to prove : $(u_k)$ is bounded $\Rightarrow \forall k \in \mathbb{N}  , |u_k|\leq 2$.

I thought argue by contrapositive but it did not seem to work.

Any hints?

Thanks.

Comment: Let $u_0$ what?

Comment: Suppose $\lvert u_k \rvert \geqslant 2+\varepsilon_k > 2$. Can you find a lower bound for $\lvert u_{k+1}\rvert$?

Comment: We're dealing with complex numbers, so in inequalities, we need the modulus to occur, not $u_{k+1}$ and $c$ themselves. And $\lvert u_{k+1}\rvert > 4 + \lvert c\rvert$ need not hold.

Comment: @Nico I did too.

Comment: Ah-ha! We're heading towards the target. How do you continue? (it must be $\geqslant$, not $>$, however)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\lvert u_{k+1}\rvert = \lvert u_k^2 + c\rvert \geqslant \lvert u_k\rvert^2 - \lvert c\rvert \geqslant \lvert u_k\rvert^2-2,$$

as you found. Now if $\lvert u_k\rvert \geqslant 2 + \varepsilon > 2$, then we obtain

$$\lvert u_{k+1}\rvert \geqslant (2+\varepsilon)^2 - 2 = 2 + 4\varepsilon + \varepsilon^2 > 2 + 4\varepsilon.$$

By induction, we find

$$\lvert u_{k+n}\rvert \geqslant 2 + 4^n\varepsilon,$$

and that is evidently unbounded for $\varepsilon > 0$.